# How to rewrite $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$ into $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(\frac{x}{n}+1\right)^n=e^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, exponential-function, exponentiation

I am trying to rewrite $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$ into $\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n=e^x$.

Developing:

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0}1 + h=\lim_{h \to 0}e^h$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1 + h\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e$$

Changing the limit variable:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e$$

Raising to the $x$-power and simplifying by the limits law of powers:

$$\left(\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^x=e^x$$
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{nx}=e^x$$

I am stuck here, I do not understand how I can substitute this $\frac{1}{n}$ into $\frac{x}{n}$ and remove the $x$-power. I am not at ease with limits and there must be something I am missing.

Comment: Instead of changing $h$ into $1/n$ change it into $x/n$.

Comment: You get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n/x} = e$. Raising both sides to the $x$ power, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$. This is exactly the variable substitution that was suggested in the answer you accepted, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems like a mix of algebraic manipulation and calculus stuff. This is wrong. Limits can be manipulated but using their own set of laws which are not exactly the same as typical rules one learns in high school algebra.

Your step $$\lim_{h\to 0}1+h=\lim_{h\to 0}e^h\implies \lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{1/h}=e$$ is clearly false. The first part of implication is true as both sides equal $1$ but it does not imply the second equation. This is because the first part remains true even if one replaces $e$ by any positive number. Following that implication it appears that $\lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{1/h}$ can take any positive value.

Your steps appear like algebraic manipulation $$\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1\implies 1+h=e^h\implies (1+h)^{1/h}=e$$ without the limit operator involved. Here the logical flow is correct but the equations are false individually. The equations in your approach are true but they don't follow logically from one another (at least not via algebraic manipulation).

Here is an even more interesting scenario :

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=y\implies\lim_{n\to\infty} n(y^{1/n}-1)=x$$ and $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=y\implies n(y^{1/n}-1)=x$$ Both the implications are true, the second one being just a matter of simple algebra. The first one is an implication with many hidden steps.

---

The correct and rigorous approach starts with a proper definition of symbol $a^b$ with $a>0,b\in\mathbb {R} $ and a study of the function $f(x) =a^x$ where $a>0$. One can prove that this function is continuous everywhere and its derivative is $$f'(x) =a^x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=a^xg(a)$$ where the limit above exists for all positive $a$ and hence defines a functions $g:\mathbb{R} ^{+} \to \mathbb{R} $.

Next one starts a study of new function $g$ and learns that $g$ is continuous and strictly increasing on its domain. Further it satisfies the following properties $$g(ab) =g(a) +g(b), \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(1+h)}{h}=1$$ Here is how one derives the first property mentioned above (at the request of asker via comments) :
\begin{align} 
g(ab) &=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(ab)^h-1}{h}\notag\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^hb^h-b^h+b^h-1}{h}\notag\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}b^h\cdot\frac{a^h-1}{h}+\frac{b^h-1}{h}\notag\\
&=1\cdot g(a) +g(b) \notag\\
&=g(a) +g(b) \notag
\end{align}

Using these properties one can easily show that $g$ is differentiable with $g'(x) =1/x$.

Another key property of $g$ is $g(a^b) =bg(a) $ for all real $b$ and this allows us to conclude that range of $g$ is whole of $\mathbb {R} $. By the strict monotone nature of $g$ it follows that there is a unique real number $e>1$ such that $g(e) =1$. And then we get $$g(e^x) =xg(e) =x$$ so that $g$ is the inverse of the specific exponential function $\exp(x)=e^x$.

We can now prove more generally that $$\lim_{h\to 0}(1+xh)^{1/h}=e^x$$ To proceed we start with the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(1+xh)}{h}=x$$ or $$\lim_{h\to 0}g((1+xh)^{1/h})=x$$ and by continuity of exponential function $\exp$ one gets $$\lim_{h\to 0}\exp(g((1+xh)^{1/h})) =\exp (x) =e^x$$ or $$\lim_{h\to 0}(1+xh)^{1/h}=e^x$$ Putting $h=1/n$ we get the desired limit formula.

Comment: Also, the expression $\lim_{h \to 0} (1 + h)^{1/h} = e$ is true. I just forgot to make it equal to $e$ for any positive real number.

Comment: @gatosec: the function $g$ is defined by $$g(a) =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$$ See the first equation where $g$ is introduced.

Comment: Also, I can't transform the expression $\lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^{1/h} = e$ into $\lim_{h \to 0}(1+xh)^{1/h} = e^x$, I tried to substitute $\frac{x}{h} = y$ into the first expression, but the limit drives me to nonsense. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like it is impossible to manipulate limits when $h \to 0$ and you end up with zero divisors.

Comment: @gatosec : let $k$ be fixed real number then $p(x) = x^k$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and hence we have $\lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{k/h}=e^k$ and putting $h/k=z$ we get $\lim_{z\to 0}(1+kz)^{1/z}=e^k$.

Comment: @gatosec : as I mentioned in my answer, limits can be manipulated but using a different set of laws compared to the usual laws of high school algebra.

Comment: Why would you let $z = \frac{h}{k}$ and not $z = hk$ specifically? The two are equivalent in sense that when $h \to 0$ then $z \to 0$ right?

Comment: @gatosec: $z=hk$ also works but in different manner. Start with $\lim_{z\to 0}(1+z)^{1/z}=e$ and put $z=hk$ to get $\lim_{h\to 0}(1+kh)^{1/kh}=e$. Raising both sides to power $k$ (this involves continuity of $p(x) =x^k$) to get $\lim_{h\to 0}(1+kh)^{1/h}=e^k$.

Comment: So, for these operations on limits, we need to find a variable $z$, expressed in terms of $h$ and the constant $k$, that would satisfies the condition "_when $h \to 0$ then $z \to 0$_" so that we can substitute $h$ by $t$. Am I right?

Comment: @gatosec: there are many rules for manipulation of limits. The one I use here is *change of variables* or *substitution rule*. Based on your goal you need to decide which rules to use. Also we are using the feature of continuity that *application of a continuous function can be interchanged with limit operation*.

Comment: If I do not use your trick you mentioned when $z = hk$, and if I choose to develop from the start, posing $z = hk \iff h = \frac{t}{k}$, I end up with $\lim_{t \to 0}(1 + \frac{t}{k})^{\frac{k^2}{t}} = e^k$, what's the problem?

Comment: @gatosec: there is no problem as you get a correct limit but not what you desire. You desire to have $k$ in numerator in the expression $(1+\dots)$ and not in the denominator.

Comment: @gatosec: another option is to put $t=nx$ (last limit in your question) so that $x/t=1/n$ and you get $(1+x/t)^t\to e^x$ as $t\to\infty $. Then just replace $t$ by $n$ and you are done.

Comment: You said the first part of implication is true as both sides equal 1 but it does not imply the second equation **however** the second equation is true in the context of $e$. The only number for which this limit is true $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$.

Comment: _"Your approach seems like a mix of algebraic manipulation and calculus stuff"_ – That is maybe true, and very unfortunate, can you highlight me what do you believe is such mix? Thank you very much. I need help with not mixing different notions in maths.

Comment: @gatosec: at the start (after "Developing") you write three equations and it appears from your writing that each equation logically implies the next. The reality is that all the three equations are true but they don't follow logically in the way they are written. However if you remove the limit operator from each of these equations, each one implies the next (but they are individually false).

Comment: I see, but how can I write this algebraic manipulations without false logical implications?

Comment: @gatosec: well you can't. You should see my updated answer for another even more interesting example. You have to work using limit laws while dealing with limits.

Comment: @gatosec: yes. There is no direct way to go from your first limit to second unless you introduce logarithms.

Comment: So the only way is to introduce the logarithm? How so? The algebraic stuff I made seems to work?

Comment: @gatosec: your stuff is not series of logical deductions but a set of independent correct statements. Its not like one statement is derived from another.

Comment: So, it is impossible to pass from $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$ to $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1 + h\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e$ without introducing the natural logarithm? Seems circular to me... Also, how can I connect my independent correct statements? I finally derived the first limit into the last one, maybe it is just luck and mixing limits and algebra usually does not work.

Comment: @gatosec: it can't be done by algebra alone.

Comment: But the two _key properties_ you introduced, namely $g(ab)=g(a)+g(b)$ and $g(a^b)=bg(a)$ are directly derived from the logarithm definition. These properties, in the case of $g$, derive from $e$. Yet, I am trying to _introduce_ $e$ through limits.

Comment: @gatosec: yes $g$ is the logarithm, but it's defined without using any $e$ stuff. You can check the definition of $g$ again.

Comment: I don't see the definition of $g$. I only see the limit where $g$ is involved. Also, how do you introduce the two _key properties_ (how do you connect $g$ to those properties). That's the most interesting part since we start from that point.

Comment: @gatosec : $g$ is defined via the limit $g(a) =\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{a^h-1}{h}$. Using this definition one can derive all the properties of $g$.

Comment: So, the actual way of manipulating limits is using variable substitution followed by a study of the increasing/decreasing domain rather than algebraic stuff? Whenever the limit operator is here I cannot modify the limit itself if I have well understood.

Comment: @gatosec there is some amount of manipulation which looks algebraic and is allowed via rules of limits. Thus if $\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f(x)-5}{x+2}=4$ then $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=5+4\lim_{x\to 2}(x+2)=21$. If you get familiar with limit laws you will figure out what is or isn't allowed.

Comment: You mean $\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{f(x)+5}{x-2}=4 \iff \frac{\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)+5}{\lim_{x \to 2}x-2}=4 \iff \lim_{x \to 2}f(x)+5 = 4 \cdot \lim_{x \to 2}x-2$ per the quotient and product rules?

Comment: _one can derive all the properties of $g$_: it would be interesting to tell us how did you derive those properties. I personally cannot recover them by myself.

Comment: @gatosec : see updated answer. Search for "here is how".

Comment: @gatosec: the approach in this answer is described in [this post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-3.html?m=0). Other approaches are described [here](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/03/theories-of-circular-functions-part-1.html?m=0) and [here](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-2_10.html?m=0).

Comment: After thinking more and more about the question of the derivative of $e^x$, and more generally to its introduction through limits, I am now pretty sure that one cannot rewrite $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$ into the Bernoulli compound interest formula $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1 + h\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e$ (used to differentiate $e^x$ term-by-term using power series). Thus, the natural logarithm is required to differentiate.

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $m=nx$ we have $n=\frac{m}{x}$ and for $x>0$ we get 
$$\lim_{m \to +\infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{m}\right)^{m}$$
$x=0$ is obvious, if $x<0$ put $y=-x$ and we get
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{ny}}$$
and then it can be treated as before.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $$t=e^h-1$$ we get $$h=\ln(t+1)$$ and our term is given by $$\frac{t}{\ln(t+1)}=\frac{1}{\ln(1+t)^{1/t}}$$ so our searched limit is given by $1$ if $t$ tends to zero.(If $h$ tends to zero so $t$ tends to zero).