# Rewrite limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$ to $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1 + h\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Rewrite limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$ to $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1 + h\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e$

Is there any (preferably simple) method of rewriting $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=1$ into $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1 + h\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e$?

You cannot use regular algebraic manipulations as it would create false logical implications:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}1+h=\lim_{h\to 0}e^h \kern.6em\not\kern -.6em \implies \lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{1/h}=e$$

Disclaimer:

I am NOT trying to prove the derivative of the exponential function here, my question is a different problem that I would like to address using ONLY limit laws, if possible. This question was [already addressed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388438/how-to-rewrite-lim-h-to-0-fraceh-1h-1-into-lim-n-to-infty-le) a few weeks earlier, but the explanation here seemed somewhat very difficult and out-of-reach of many calculus students like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a change of variable $h=\log (1+x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$ we have

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{\log (1+x)} - 1}{\log (1+x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\log (1+x)}\color{blue}{\cdot\frac{\frac1x}{\frac1x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1{\color{blue}{\frac1x}\log (1+x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{\log (1+x)^\color{blue}{\frac1x}}=1$$

which implies

$$\lim_{x \to 0}(1+x)^\frac1x=e$$

Comment: This correlates perfectly with the other answer. The only requirements is to **admit** the natural logarithm is the inverse of the exponential

Comment: Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: @gatosec Yes we need to assume that. Are you looking for something different?

Comment: No. It's just kinda weird that to prove $e^x$ is its own derivative from power series later, you need to rewrite this limit to the more common Bernoulli compound interest formula (the formula that precisely defines $e$ as the growth constant) and for that you need the natural logarithm (the inverse of what we are trying to prove).

Comment: @gatosec If you have a "nice" power series then you can differentiate term by term https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/uniform.pdf So from the power series of $\exp$ it is easy to see that $\exp$ is its own derivative

Comment: Surely you understand that you should have learned about the inverse nature of the relationship between exponential and logarithmic functions before learning about calculus.  The derivative of the exponential function need not be proven with power series; logarithmic differentiation also proves it just fine.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch yes. But again, generally we expand $e^x$ to the general power series $e^x = 1 + \frac{x}{1!} + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ...$ through the binomial theorem, and it is usually expanded from the Bernoulli compound formula $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$

Comment: @AndrewChin I am not trying to learn anything new here, but rather I try to avoid being circular in some interconnected definitions of the exponential function.

Comment: @AndrewChin it is not obvious to everyone which rule you used to transform $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\log (1+x)}$ into $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{\log (1+x)^\frac1x}=1$. Consider adding a step please.

Comment: If it's not obvious to _you_, why not just say that? Either way, it's not my answer, but I can edit something in if you like @gatosec

Comment: @AndrewChin it is not obvious to me and I don't recall any limit law to do so.

Comment: It's a law of logarithms, edited in blue into the answer by @user.

Comment: Looks nice and easy but I still don't understand how I can find such variable substitutions. I just can't wrap my mind around these. To understand them is one thing, to find them another.

Comment: @gatosec Maybe this [ProofWiki article](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Euler%27s_Number) is also helpful

Comment: @gatosec And also [this one](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Exponential_at_Zero) In particular, proof 2 doesn't suppose any knowledge about $\exp'$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch yes, but still, the proof no. 2 still involves the sequence $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n$ as the definition of the constant e. This feels circular, since this definition is not trivially deduced from the limit definition of the derivative $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h - 1}{h}$. Maybe I should just accept it (I learned this in university few years ago without thinking too much about it, actually).

Comment: Some books may introduce the number e in a different manner, one with usually start with a generalized study of exponential functions of base $a^x$, and will use the limit definition of a derivative to notice that all exponential applications are proportional to a constant given by the limit $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{a^h - 1}{h}$ and the immediate consequence of a given base a where $a^x$ would be proportional to itself follows, such as $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{a^h - 1}{h} = 1$. This is where we introduce the number e as the base for which this limit is true.

Comment: However, in order to have a nice proof of this conjecture, the solid method is to define the number e as the following $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac1n\right)^n$ (known as the Bernoulli compound formula), and use binomial expansion to a power series, then a term-by-term differentiation and induction principle will show $(e^x)' = e^x$. However, introducing the number e through the Bernoulli compound formula is not directly related to the previous limit you can encounter while using the limit definition of a derivative on exponentials.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, if you have any thoughts on it, you're welcome.